# converting from iterator to the object c++

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have an iterator that going over a list, and I try to convert the iterator to the object.

```
std::list<XMLObjects>::const_iterator objectsIterator;
for (objectsIterator = frame->getObjectsList().begin(); objectsIterator != frame->getObjectsList().end(); ++objectsIterator)
    {
      XMLObjects object =(*objectsIterator);
    }
```

but I get an error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA9A658384 in OR_Comparator.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location
>   0x0000007C0196C490.

who can I convert it in a good way?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA9A658384 in OR_Comparator.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0000007C0196C490.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: FWIW, the parentheses around `*objectsIterator` aren't needed.

Comment: Wow, nearly 2 years down the line you come back to include the error? I'm impressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write

```
std::list<XMLObjects>::iterator objectsIterator;
```

instead of

```
std::list<XMLObjects>::const_iterator objectsIterator;
```

and then write in the for:

```
xmlObjects &gt=(*objectsIterator);
```